# Bread Book Suggestions

Tags: baking, bread, resources, cookbook

I want baking my own bread loafs, specially things like sourdough baguettes, ciabatta, flatbead, and multi grain loaf bread.

I've been researching this for a few days, but as usual, there is a tremendous information overload, and I'm not sure if/which book I should get, or is there an online place that would have me better covered.

I'm the kind of person that do actually enjoy knowing the whys and hows of how things work, but I also appreciate quick recipes, so a mix of those two would be great!

Is there any specific book/author/resource that you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Francisco, book suggestions are generally considered off-topic across the network, sorry. You can get some advice in our chat room, The Frying pan.

Comment: A bit of discussion of bread books in the chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11739134#11739134

Comment: Hey, sorry I know this is kind a very subjective question, but I was just hopping to see if there was a kind of "universally accepted" resources, the GOTO book that everybody agrees (to a degree) that is a good resource. Thanks for the Chat link though!

Answer (score 1):

How about a good website? http://www.kingarthurflour.com/ Be aware that the brand of flour that website stresses measures and behaves slightly differently than other brands of flour, but they are *usually* interchangeable. In other words, a recipe on that site will always say such and such amount of a particular type (bread flour, all-purpose flour, whole wheat flour) of *King Arthur Flour*. 99 times out of 100 another brand of the same type of flour will give the same results.

I love that the recipes convert from volumetric to weight with one click of the mouse. Also, the reviews are very helpful.